# How to use Scaldi Conditions to do default binding

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0, slick, scaldi

I am using Scaldi with Play and Slick in my application.

I need to bind a DatabaseConfig dependency to different configurations depending on  some condition.

- Mode = Dev => Oracle DB
- Mode = UAT => Another Oracle DB
  ...
- Mode = Test => Local H2 DB
- No Mode specified => same as Mode = Test

How do I handle the last part? I tried to do the following but it does not work.

```
  val inDevMode = SysPropCondition(name = "mode", value = Some("dev"))
  val inTestMode = SysPropCondition(name = "mode", value = Some("test")) or SysPropCondition(name = "mode", value = None)

  bind [DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]] when (inDevMode) to new DbConfigHelper().getDecryptedConfig("gem2g") destroyWith (_.db.close)
  bind [DatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile]] when (inTestMode) to DatabaseConfig.forConfig[JdbcProfile]("h2") destroyWith (_.db.close)
```

Answer (score 0):

val inTestMode = SysPropCondition(name=MODE, value=Some("test")) or SysPropCondition(name=MODE, value=None) or
    Condition(System.getProperty(MODE) == null)